# Не выводиться информация

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Не выводиться никакой информации(ошибок тоже нет), хотя таблица не не пустая

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("lol13",$conn);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM('sumer') FROM 'out' WHERE 'idu'='$udi'");
echo $sql;
```

Comment: А почему она должна выводиться? Читайте мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2):

Если прочитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) то найдете следующие строки:

> Полученный дескриптор результата нужно передать в функцию
>   mysql_fetch_assoc() или любую другую функцию, работающую с
>   результатами запросов.

К примеру, если Вы хотите получить результат то должны сделать следующиее:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM('sumer') as `total`  FROM 'out' WHERE 'idu'='$udi'");
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo $values['total'];
```